# Store and call favorite bash commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm searching for a Linux command line tool that allows me to store my *favorite / most used / most difficult to remember* bash commands and quickly run them when needed.

I prefer not using aliases because I want to avoid names conflict. `alias` is a handy thing, but it's not what I'm searching, that is some *command line snippets library*.

An example of what I want is:

```
$ favorite --add hello 'echo Hello World!'
$ favorite hello
Hello World!
$ favorite --delete hello
$ favorite hello
favorite: shortcut 'hello' not defined
$ _
```

I think I'm able to code this tool by myself (maybe using *python-cliapp* or *php5-cli*), but if something already exists I prefer not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The commands I reuse usually need some modification before re-execution. What I do is to have a large history file (5000+ lines) and regex search with <C-r> for partials.

Comment: Learn the CLI backwards and forwards.  After that the only think you need is your memory, and the ability to type fast.  I find it much easier trying to remember the standard selection of commands, then trying to the name of alias, scripts, other memory crutches.  Plus I can be useful on a machine without any aliases or so on.

Comment: @Thor I owe you a beer for making me discover reverse intelligent history search.

Comment: @lorenzo-s If you're really ok with typing "favorite" before every snippet, why don't you just alias with a prefix: alias fav-hello='echo Hello World!' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind lack of error messages for syntax errors etc., you can use this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
  --add)
    if [ -a ~/.favorites/$2 ]; then
      echo favorite: Shortcut \'$2\' already exists.
    else
      echo $3 >> ~/.favorites/$2
    fi
  ;;
  --delete)
    if [ -a ~/.favorites/$2 ]; then
      rm ~/.favorites/$2
    else
      echo favorite: Shortcut \'$2\' does not exist.
    fi
  ;;
  *)
    if [ -a ~/.favorites/$1 ]; then
      $(cat ~/.favorites/$1)
    else
      echo favorite: Shortcut \'$1\' does not exist.
    fi
esac
```

Comment: I think your use of `$3` is problematic.  I think you want to shift off the first two positional parameters and use `$*` instead.

Comment: Since the OP quotes the command (`favorite --add hello 'echo Hello World!'`), `$3` becomes `echo Hello World!`.

Comment: True, but without quotes typed by the user, it malfunctions.  But since the author is the user, that's probably ok.

Comment: I like it for the simplicity :) +1

Answer (score 8):

It seems that writing scripts and putting them in `~/bin` (which would then be in your `PATH`) is an acceptable alternative.  That would work unless you want to be able to see and edit the command before pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to execute it, but your example above does not demonstrate that requirement.